# system.directoryservices - Add users to group with samaccountname

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, interop, directoryservices

I am trying to add over 100 users to a active directory group. But I have onlz their samaccountnames. I dont want to run a loop to find their DN I am trying to find if there is a way to add the users in bulk just with their samaccountnames.

```
string userSAm = string.Format("<sAMAccountName={0}>", samAccountName);

                        groupDirectoryEntry.Properties["member"].Add(userSAm);
                        groupDirectoryEntry.CommitChanges();
```

It is possible with SID though

```
string userSid = string.Format("<SID={0}>", sid);

                        groupDirectoryEntry.Properties["member"].Add(userSid);
                        groupDirectoryEntry.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: No, there isn't - you need the user's **DN** to add it to the group. If you only have the `samAccountName`, you'll have to lookup the DN's first, then add those

Comment: I believe DN is not the only way. If we have a SID, with that we can achieeve it. So using the SID is one way, similarly there might b other ways